# How to run Dataflow from python Google API Client Libraries on private subnetwork

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am trying to launch a Dataflow job using the python google api client libraries. Everything worked fine previously, until we had to migrate from default subnetwork to another private subnetwork. Previously I was launching a dataflow job with the following code:

```
    request = dataflow.projects().locations().templates().launch(
        projectId = PROJECT_ID,
        location  = REGION,
        gcsPath   = TEMPLATE_LOCATION,
        body      = {
            'jobName':    job_name,
            'parameters': job_parameters,
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
```

However the job now will fail because the default subnetwork does not exist anymore, and I now need to specify to use `data-subnet` subnetwork.
From [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#python) documentation and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122626/how-to-run-dataflow-python-on-a-private-subnetwork) other question, the solution would be trivial if i were to launch the script from command line by adding the flag `--subnetwork regions/$REGION/subnetworks/$PRIVATESUBNET`. However my case is different becuase I am trying to do it from code, and in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.templates/launch) I can't find any subnet parameter option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom subnetwork like so to your pipeline

```py
    request = dataflow.projects().locations().templates().launch(
        projectId = PROJECT_ID,
        location  = REGION,
        gcsPath   = TEMPLATE_LOCATION,
        body      = {
            'jobName':    job_name,
            'parameters': job_parameters,
            'environment': {
                'subnetwork': SUBNETWORK,
            }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
```

Make sure SUBNETWORK is in the form `"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-id>/regions/<region>/subnetworks/<subnetwork-name>"`